# permission from Asus( autostart manager ) ,miui (security center)

Tags: android, autostart

Is there any way to take permission from Asus( autostart manager ) ,miui (security center) programmatically ? As these apps disable auto start feature of an app

Comment: Do you got any solution on this ?

Comment: not yet!  as these security app a system app so it is not possible to bypass

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843579/set-allow-permission-by-default-in-asus-auto-start-manager-from-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check MIUI autostart permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366231/how-to-check-miui-autostart-permission-programmatically)