# Set "allow" permission by default in "Asus auto start manager" from code

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-intentservice, android-background

I have an application which needs to run in the background, so I'm using a WakeFullService for that. But in Asus Zenfone it's not working because Auto start manager does not allow the app to run. My expectation is:

1. To set "allow permission" in auto start manager during our app install or at the time of app opening.
2. Is there any API available from ASUS Auto Start Manager which can help me check the permission status of my app so that I can notify the user via normal text alert to turn on the permission.

Comment: have you already found any solutions?

Comment: To handle this (not solve) I create an intent like this:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.MainActivity");
And check if the intent is valid. (Only tried it on an ASUS AR)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Any solution so far? This battery optimization is killing our apps and killing customers trust on us. It is one of the worst solutions from Android. They should make an standard api to remove our apps from optimization. Just like any other run-time permission.

Answer (score 1):

Someone did it for Huawei:

["Protected Apps" setting on Huawei phones, and how to handle it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638986/protected-apps-setting-on-huawei-phones-and-how-to-handle-it)

It would be nice a library / class to detect most common "task killers" (preinstalled or not) and letting user know that they need to disable them (and why) to let some feature work, like beacon detection.