# How to give auto start permission for android app in ASUS Zenfone?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, asus

How to give permission to run app in background on ASUS devices.
It has been done for Mi devices [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814126/gcm-push-notifications-for-android-devices-are-not-working-on-mi-and-letv-mobile/40932178#40932178)

When I installed Truecaller on ASUS it asked for background permission and app is given autostart permission programatically.

I want to achieve that pictures are attached.
[truecaller dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMj0y.jpg)
[auto start permission given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OtBM.jpg)

Comment: There's a comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38843579/2232127 which might work. Don't know much more though.